# Backbonejs having trouble with a get request inside of my view

Tags: jquery, ajax, backbone.js, coffeescript

i'm trying to make a get request in my backbonejs views render method.  On the success of the ajax call, i'd like to render my template.  I'm having an issue though accessing my model that is passed into the view originally.  I only have access to the data from the ajax request.  How can I get my @user model available to me in the success of the ajax call?

```
FooAdmin.Views.Users ||= {}

class FooAdmin.Views.Users.ShowView extends Backbone.View    
  initialize: ->
    @user = @model

  template: HandlebarsTemplates["users/show"]

  render: ->   
    @self = @$el.html
    $.ajax FooAdmin.FOO_API_URL + "/api/v1/orders?user_id=#{@user.attributes.id}",
      type: 'GET'
      dataType: 'json'

      error: (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) ->
        alert(textStatus)
      success: (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->
        debugger;
        @self.html(@template(user: @user, order: data))
```

Comment: You probably have to bind the success call to the parent object. Bypassing Backbone and using jQuery will not preserve context. I typically use _.bind for this type of thing.

Comment: It looks like when i'm I check the parent where the `debugger` is placed, the parent is window.

Comment: `@self = @$el.html` doesn't make a lot of sense, that leaves a function reference in `@self` and `@` won't necessarily be what you want it to be in the `success` callback. Don't you want something more like `el = @$el` and then `el.html(...)` in the callback? Also, `FooAdmin.FOO_API_URL + "/api/v1/orders?user_id=#{@user.attributes.id}"` could be just `"#{FooAdmin.FOO_API_URL}/api/v1/orders?user_id=#{@user.attributes.id}"` which looks a bit more consistent.

Comment: Am I able to do something like this before the ajax call to have access to the user object?  `user = @user`  That directly doesn't work, but maybe there is a similar function.

Answer (score 0):

It's the scoping of your **@** reference inside your **success** function that is causing the problem.  At this point **@** is no longer referring to your class as you expect.  Typically with something like this I will add an explicit reference to the class or object to in internal function.  See the first line of **render**, below, and the change replacing **@** with **thisRef** inside of **success**.

```
FooAdmin.Views.Users ||= {}

class FooAdmin.Views.Users.ShowView extends Backbone.View    
  initialize: ->
    @user = @model

  template: HandlebarsTemplates["users/show"]

  render: ->   
    thisRef = @
    @self = @$el
    $.ajax FooAdmin.FOO_API_URL + "/api/v1/orders?user_id=#{@user.attributes.id}",
      type: 'GET'
      dataType: 'json'

      error: (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) ->
        alert(textStatus)
      success: (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->
        debugger;
        thisRef.self.html(thisRef.template(user: thisRef.user, order: data))
```

Comment: `thisRef` doesn't seem to be available inside of success.  Getting this error: `show_view.self-3d520d9….js?body=1:45 Uncaught TypeError: thisRef.self.html is not a function`

Comment: I think the issue you are seeing here isn't that thisRef is unavailable.  It's that thisRef.self.html isn't a function.  The assignment above, `@self = $el.html` is actually assigning the html method to @self (this.self), so the call, **thisRef.self.html** is equivalent to **$el.html.html**, which is the issue I think.  One solution would be to just change the **@self** assignment to instead be `@self = @$el`.  I'll update the example.